# angular how to get Element by observable

Tags: angular

I have a question about angular observable, I just created a test component for get key-up event with observable :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">`,
})

export class AppComponent { 

constructor(){  
    var keyup = Observable.fromEvent(*****,"keyup");
    keyup.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}

}
```

how can i call input item by id or etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you can use (see [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WhInCA1ZQc2TxdBYyJQ5)):

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
             <input type="text" name="name" id="name" #nameInput>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('nameInput')
  nameInput:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var keyup = Observable.fromEvent(this.nameInput.nativeElement, 'keyup');
    keyup.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

}
```

This [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248) may be of interest.

Comment: thanks for your fast and perfect solution, but i wonder if there is any other solution?

Comment: You also have [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and `valueChanges` `Observable`. Or you could listen to change events: `<input (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">`